# Direct current electric circuit

Tags: electricity, electric-circuits, batteries

Why when I reverse one of the three batteries in a torch light, the bulb does not light up? 
The three batteries (one of them is reversed) and the bulb suppose to form a closed loop. 
According to Kirchhoff's 2nd law,

$IR = E_1 + E_2 - E_3$

If all the batteries are identical ($1.5$ V for example), then IR$ = 1.5$V. That means there is still an electric current flows through the bulb. 
Is there any reason why the bulb does not light up?

Comment: Have you thought about the current not being strong enough?

Comment: Is it an incandescent bulb, or an LED?

Comment: Re, "That means there is still an electric current flows through the bulb."  Not true if the "bulb" actually is an LED.  An LED is a _diode_, not a resistor. It does not obey Ohm's Law.  (see https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/blog/i-v-characteristic-curves.html).  A "white" LED might not glow at all if you supply it with only 1.5V.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you are correct that the net voltage in the circuit is 1.5 V. You can be assured of it using a multi meter. The bulb of your flashlight is designed to use 4.5 V but you say that you are just powering it with a 1.5 V battery as the other 2 batteries are no use. This way there is just $\frac{1}{3}$rd the voltage it was designed to work with .

Simply said, that small voltage might not be enough to produce a considerable current through your bulb in the circuit.

Comment: Thank you for your response. But, I have tried with a 1.1 V bulb and it still couldn't light up. Is there any other possibility?

Comment: was it a filament bulb or an led? There is a possibility of the battery being dead or the bulb being broken